# Distance between two vertices in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

If $e(x)=\underset{y \in V(G)}{\text{max}}\{d(x,y)\}$ then prove $|e(u)-e(v)| \leq d(u, v)$.

I know that $e(u)\geq d(u,v)$ and $e(v) \geq d(u, v)$, but how do I prove the difference is less than or equal to? I've tried saying that $e(u)=d(u,v)+a$ and $e(v)=d(u,v)+b$ but that just leads me to $a-b$ and I'm not sure how to prove that $a-b \leq d(u,v)$. Is it possible for both $a$ and $b$ to be greater than $d(u,v)$?

Comment: Should the right hand side of the definition of $e(x)$ contain $u$ or $v$? I believe that it perhaps should read: $$e(x) = \max_{y \in V(G)} \{d(x,y)\}.$$ Does that seem correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry I corrected it.

Comment: Is the graph connected?

Comment: Yes, the graph is connected.

Answer (score 1):

suppose the graph is connected. Then every path with longest possible length with one end $u$ should intersects every longest path with with one end $v$. Suppose $v$ is the first intersection of these two paths. Try to prove the length from $v$ until the ends of two paths is equal or the difference is just $1$ edge(Consider beginnings of paths be $u$ and $v$)!

Comment: if the $v$ and $u$ are not connected then $d(u,v)$ is equal to infinity!